# Customize className seen in the DOM with react css modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, classname, react-css-modules

I was thinking, when I use react css modules I end up with visible class names like **Form__module_bhj34** (something like this).

What is my goal, to get rid of the first and second part and end up jsut with that generated id, hope I am not the only one weirdo who cares about these details.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: What is my goal, after deploying I want my classes to be visible just like [bhj34] - from example above, since now it looks exactly like the whole bold part and I personaly don't like it. I know (at least 95% sure) that's possible as I've seen this kind of class names on many websites. I **I guess** it might be something with **webpack** configuration but I haven't found anyting relatable

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.